# How to count vowels

Tags: abap

How can I count the vowels in a string ?

for example:

```
data: str type string  value 'steave'.
```

and I want the output be:

```
2 --> e.
1 --> a.
```

Comment: Do you mean wovels when you say 'vogals'?

Comment: @SergioPrats Do you mean vowels when you say 'wovels'? :P

Comment: Yes... not the best correction ever done :S

Answer (score 1):

I  seriously thought you were making up words at random.  <s>I hope 'vogals' are characters</s>. Vogals I've been told, are vowels. Thank @jmoerdyk. Anyway, since you got me interested I think this may work:

```
vowels = 'aeiouy'
length = STRLEN(vowels).
WHILE index < length.
  char = vowels+index(1).
  FIND ALL OCCURENCES OF char IN yourString
  MATCH COUNT  occurrences
  WRITE: / char,'appears', / occurrences,'times'
  ADD 1 TO index.
ENDWHILE.
```

Seems difficult working for SAP. The language seems to work well with tables/databases, not these kind of string operations.

Comment: I'm guessing from the fact that they only referenced counts for 'a' and 'e', that perhaps vogal == vowel.

Comment: @jmoerdyk Good catch, I'll amend.

Answer (score 1):

Just loop through the string / char and collect the results into a statistical internal table. Use `CA` (contains any) operator for checking vowels. Example code:

```
DATA: str TYPE string VALUE 'steave',
      l_pos TYPE sy-index,
      BEGIN OF ls_stat,
        char TYPE c,
        count TYPE sy-index,
      END OF ls_stat,
      lt_stat LIKE STANDARD TABLE OF ls_stat.

DO strlen( str ) TIMES.
  l_pos = sy-index - 1 .
  IF str+l_pos(1) CA 'AaEeIiOoUu'.
    ls_stat-char = str+l_pos(1).
    ls_stat-count = 1.
    COLLECT ls_stat INTO lt_stat.
  ENDIF.
ENDDO.

SORT lt_stat BY count DESCENDING.
LOOP AT lt_stat INTO ls_stat.
  WRITE: / ls_stat-count, '->', ls_stat-char.
ENDLOOP.
```